# In Postgres, how can I calculate cume_dist (relative rank) over the entire table, but only for a single row?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  data  TEXT   NOT NULL,
  count BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (data)
);
```

I'd like to get the relative rank of a single entry, based on `count`, as it relates to the entire table, but I'm not sure how to structure the `OVER` clause in order to do this. Running the following gives me a rank of 1, so I'm assuming the `OVER` clause is getting limited to a single row, rather than all the rows in the table, as dictated by the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT cume_dist() OVER(ORDER BY f.count ASC) AS rank
FROM foo AS f
  WHERE f.data = 'bar';

rank 
------
    1
(1 row)
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first apply the function in the whole table and then restrict the results with `WHERE`:

```
SELECT r.rank
FROM
  ( SELECT f.data, cume_dist() OVER (ORDER BY f.count ASC) AS rank
    FROM foo AS f
  ) AS r
WHERE r.data = 'bar';
```

Alternatively, you could calculate the function with 2 subqueries:

```
SELECT
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM foo 
      WHERE count <= (SELECT count FROM foo WHERE data = 'bar')
    ) 
  * 1.0 /
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo )
  AS rank ;
```

or with the new `FILTER` syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER 
                (WHERE f.count <= (SELECT count FROM foo WHERE data = 'bar')) 
       * 1.0 / COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM foo AS f ;
```

Comment: OK, thanks! So does this have the effect of calculating the relative rank for each row in the table? If so, I'm hoping to avoid this since my table currently has ~7M rows in it and I really only need the rank for one of them.

Comment: Yes, it will probably do that. Check the alternative solutions, too.

Comment: Thanks again, that works! I'm sad though that it kills the option of using the `IN` clause with `WHERE`. I should have mentioned in my OP that I'll need to do this for at most 10 specific rows (out of the ~7M rows) on each query. I'll either try to figure out how to use `WHERE IN` with one of your alternatives or run the 10 queries in parallel from my application code.